# Grouping and Transforming Pandas Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series data set whith 10 units of oberservation. On each day each unit of observation may engage in an activity for a number of hours. I have therefore (lets say) 4 variables in a DataFrame:

Date - date
Unit - unit of observation
acitvity - some activity
CumHours - the cumulative number of hours spent by a unit on an activity.

I need to create an 'Hours_calc' variable that says how many hours were spent on any activity by each line on each day. After importing all the normal bits an pieces I do this:

```
DF = (mydata, columns = ['Date', 'Unit', 'Activity', 'CumHours'])
DF['Hours_calc'] = np.nan
DFGrouped = DF.groupby(['Unit', 'Activity'])
```

I believe I need the transform method, and I think that the first argument passed to the transform function (as specified) is the DF column as a series as with the agg() method. Is that right?

I wrote the following function, but as you will see I have no idea whether for the calculation I should be referring to DF or DFGrouped, or what? In general how to refer to rows/columns within goruped data? Also, am I right to try to return a series the same length as the groupby group?

```
def WorkingHours(x, Column):
    LISTHOURS = []
    for row in xrange(1, len(x)):
        Tot = int(DFGrouped[Column][row]) - int(DFGrouped[Column][row - 1])
        LISTHOURS.append(Tot)
    return pd.Series(LISTHOURS)

TESTDF = DFGrouped.transform({Hours_calc : lambda x : WorkingHours(x, 'CumHours')})
```

Also I am not seeing anything in the documentation about passing a Dict to transform, but I can't see any other way of performing the function on only one variable/column in the gorup.

Where Am I going wrong? The error message is long an confusing but ends in "Transform function invalid for data types"

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but shouldn't you group by Date, Unit instead of by Unit and Activity? This way you could just use sum of CumHours for each group to get the total hours spend on all activities.

Comment: I dont think so, I need a daily amount of hours spent on any activity. So for example, imagine in the time period unit1 does two activites, not necessarily on consecutive days. The CumHours measures cumulative time spent by that unit on the activity undertaken that day. In order to find the daily hours measure I need to take the cumulative hours on a given day and subtract the cumulative hours from the last day on which that activity was performed. Hence the grouping by unit/activity and sorting by date.,

Comment: could you provide the example of data file with some data filled in?

Comment: I can provide some ilustrative data. Do you think the syntax/concept is right?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use shift function to shift the column in grouped data by one row. Then, if you subtract original and shifted, you'll get the raw number of hours spent on the activity.

```
df = (mydata, columns = ['date', 'unit', 'activity', 'cumhours'])
grouped = df.groupby(['unit', 'activity'])
shift_it = lambda x: (x - x.shift())
raw_hours = grouped.cumhours.transform(shift_it)
df.insert(0, 'raw_hours',raw_hours)
```

EDIT 1. 
If you want general function to iterate through the series elements using transform, but without copying to list, try this:

```
df = (mydata, columns = ['date', 'unit', 'activity', 'cumhours'])
grouped = df.groupby(['unit', 'activity'])
def trans_func(x):
    y=x.copy()
    for i in range(1,len(x.index)):
        x.iloc[i]=y.iloc[i]-y.iloc[i-1]
    return x

raw_hours = gr['cumhours'].transform(lambda x: trans_func(x))
df.insert(0, 'raw_hours',raw_hours)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I am still wondering how I am supposed to refer to the rows contained within the grouped data, and make changes to the underlying data. I think this solution basically could work, but it is based on doing the same thing to every row of data, whereas I think I want to be able to write a function that iterates thorugh each row and makes changes based upon my function. Any ideas?

Comment: to iterate throught the rows you can use iloc function, see above

Answer (score 1):

I think I have finally solved the problem. I suspect that yemu's answer is good, but I prefer this as it was an exercise in finally learning how to apply my own functions:

```
DF = (mydata, columns = ['Date', 'Unit', 'Activity', 'CumHours'])
DF['Hours_calc'] = np.nan
DFGrouped = DF.groupby(['Unit', 'Activity'])

def WorkingHours(x):
    CumHoursList = list(x)
    HoursCalcList = []
    HoursCalcList.insert(0, CumHoursList[0])
    for index in xrange(1, len(CumHoursList)):
        CalcHoursList/insert(index, CumHoursList[index] - CumHoursList[index - 1])
    return CalcHoursList

DFGrouped['CumHours'].transform(lambda x: WorkingHours(x))
```

Works a charm!

Comment: Although I still think there must be a way to iterate through the Series that is passed as x without having to turn it into a list. But this solution works for me for now.

Comment: edited my answer to include more general solution that's not using a list

Comment: You can call a function directly with transform, wrapping it in a `lambda` is not necessary: `.transform(WorkingHours)`